# Assign objects data into another object with out passing reference in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class ABC
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
ABC _prevABC;
ABC abc;
public void A()
{
    _prevABC = new ABC();
    _prevABC = abc;
    abc.x = 10;
}
public void B()
{
    abc = _prevABC;
}
```

In above methods I called `A` and then `B` , even then `abc.x` value is 10 which I updated in A.

So it seems even though I created new Object of `ABC` and assigning with `=` its just passing reference.

How to assign with out passing reference?

Comment: You need to make a copy.  Basically it looks like you want to use a struct instead of a class.

Comment: Or just a deep copy/clone of the class.

Comment: First, you create a new ABC and **then throw it away in the next line**, and **replace** it with a reference to `abc`. Then everything does just what you'd expect: You carefully made both `_prevABC` and `abc` refer to the same object. And so they do. If you want a copy, make a copy. Nothing you do here makes a copy. You need to understand the difference between reference and value types in C#.

Comment: Use `struct` instead of `class` or create new instance then copy the variables manually.

Comment: What outcome are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_prevABC = abc` line is making you problem, you assign reference of abc to _prevABC.
If your class actually holds only some values like in example you gave you could use struct because it assigns values instead reference.

If you want to keep class then you could do something like this:

```
_prevABC = new ABC();
_prevABC.x = abc.x;
```